# PC Startup - 7022 Service Control Manager (hung)

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, services

I'm experiencing a problem when my computer starts. Apparently - according to the system event-log - a service hung on startup. (Having my Windows set to English I'm unsure why there's a German word included but well...)

```
The Geräteinstallations-Manager service hung on starting.
^^^ Device-Installation-Manager ^^^
```

This seems to slow down my startup every time, be it a restart, crash or simply startup, by almost exactly one minute. Right after the error log, there's an information log, also with source set to `Service Control Manager`.

```
The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) did not load: 
dam
```

My PC is a self-build, all updates are installed, running Windows 8.1 Pro.

Google has some sources for Windows 2000 and other outdated ways... does anyone know how this could be fixed ?
*I also did sfc /scannow.*

Comment: There does not seem to be a problem with the `dam` driver. I can set via registry the start value to 3 to delay the start. Changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

MS source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/desktop-activity-moderator

"The DAM is a kernel-mode driver that is loaded and initialized at system boot if the system supports connected standby."

It seems that the self-build hardware allows connected standby and the kernel is trying to load the driver before any user process is started.

You should check that the delay does not come from a boot time or system driver with higher priority (parent driver).

Does this happen on boot to Safe mode? (dam is not needed here I think) 
So you can exclude all drivers started in safe mode from check.

Comment: See my comment on my question regarding `dam`. I will check the safe mode later today, thank you. The problem is still the `Device-Installation-Manager` service.

Comment: You can use "DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth" to fix component store, then sfc.exe to fix system files and then update to get security patches - this will eventually correct some problem in software if present. But maybe its a hardware problem - why is dam not loading - something it depends on is not OK!